# Inappropriate def function?

Tags: python

I want to define a function and apply it for my data.
I thought that I was able to create a function, but it did not work.

data is the name of my data, and a1 is the column that has either 1 or 0.
0 means male and 1 means female in the data.

```
def sex(a1):
    if data['a1'] == 0:
        return '男性'
    else:
        return '女性'
data.apply(sex)
```

I executed it and got the error message below.

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 data.apply(sex)
>
> c:\users\jupyter-notebook\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
>   apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args,
>   **kwds)    6904             kwds=kwds,    6905         )
>   -> 6906         return op.get_result()    6907     6908     def applymap(self, func):
>
> c:\users\01037485\jupyter-notebook\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py
>   in get_result(self)
>       184             return self.apply_raw()
>       185 
>   --> 186         return self.apply_standard()
>       187 
>       188     def apply_empty_result(self):
>
> c:\users\jupyter-notebook\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in
>   apply_standard(self)
>       290 
>       291         # compute the result using the series generator
>   --> 292         self.apply_series_generator()
>       293 
>       294         # wrap results
>
> c:\users\jupyter-notebook\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in
>   apply_series_generator(self)
>       319             try:
>       320                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
>   --> 321                     results[i] = self.f(v)
>       322                     keys.append(v.name)
>       323             except Exception as e:
>
> in sex(a1)
>         1 def sex(a1):
>   ----> 2     if data['a1'] == 0:
>         3         return '男性'
>         4     else:
>         5         return '女性'
>
> c:\users\jupyter-notebook\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in
>   **nonzero**(self)    1554             "The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "    1555             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(),
>   a.any() or a.all().".format(
>   -> 1556                 self.**class**.**name**    1557             )    1558         )
>
> ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index cp_id')

I want to create a new column named 'sex', which has either male or female depending on the value of a1, and add the sex column to data.

Comment: please fix identaion in your code

Comment: Yep. Do that and provide a [mcve] extracted from your code. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Look at what the function takes as a parameter `a1` and then what the function does - it never uses `a1`, it only uses the string `'a1'` - not the same thing.

When doing `data['a1'] == 0` you compare the whole column to the value 0, which is the ValueError you are getting. The function needs to take `data` as a parameter instead so that it works row by row instead of on the whole column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I understand column `a1` in a pandas dataframe data has values 0 or 1 representing male or female. You can apply the function `sex` to this column as follows:

```
def sex(num):
    if num == 0:
        return '男性'
    else:
        return '女性'

data['sex'] = data['a1'].apply(sex)
print(data)
```

results in

```
   a1  sex
0   0   男性
1   1   女性
2   0   男性
3   0   男性
4   1   女性
5   1   女性
```

Answer (score 5):

Use lambda function to apply such a transformation on dataFrame. Lambda function is more generic as you can then build many complex logic out of a given row of dataFrame and use the output maybe in an additional column. I think what you are trying to do is something like the below, where if value in column a1 is 0 or non-zero determines sex:

```
def sex(row):
    if row['a1'] == 0:
        return '男性'
    else:
        return '女性'
data["sex"] = data.apply(lambda row: sex(row), axis = 1)
```